# Why no Polaris distance in GAIA DR2?

Tags: parallax, gaia

Querying GAIA DR2 for Polaris (for example using https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/) yields empty parallax columns. Anyone knows why it was not measured/published?

Comment: For source id 576402619921505664 I also see phot_g_mean_mag at about 10.45 -- perhaps this isn't actually Polaris (what search did you do?)

Comment: Yes, I filled Polaris in Name box and submitted, got that source id. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My query for stars north of +75° and brighter than magnitude 4 returns only 6 stars, brightest of which is γ Cephei.
Polaris may be [too bright for Gaia](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/faqs#BrightStar).
Even if it doesn't saturate the detector, a bright star will probably have larger astrometric errors than a star between magnitudes 6 and 12.
DR2 coverage of magnitude 5 and brighter stars is better than DR1 but still rather sparse.
Section 3.1 of [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018A%26A...616A...1G/abstract) plots parallax coverage vs. magnitude and explains why some stars have positions but not parallaxes.

Comment: Polaris has magnitude close to 2, and and GAIA DR2 states that its bright limit is at about mag 3, so Polaris is too bright to be in the catalogue